# Scrapy runspider command line arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, command-line-arguments

I have a scrapy spider I wrote. It uses gcp datastore. When I write data to the datastore I need to specify a namespace. That namespace isn't the same for each run of the script. How do I pass a commandline argument to `scrapy runspider spider.py`? I found another post on stackoverflow that had a way to pass arguments when you use `scrapy crawl spider.py`. Crawl doesnt appear to work for me. I need a way to do this using `runspider`. Any insight?

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spider-arguments

Comment: As I mentioned, I need a solution for `runspider` not `crawl`, unless you can tell me some way to change between the two of them.

Answer (score 0):

So. The scrapy documentation says you can pass arguments through `-a key=value`. In all of its examples it provides examples using `crawl` not `runspider`. When I use `crawl`, it's not even a supported command, and I'm using scrapy 2.3.0, which according to the site at the time of this writing, is the latest version. So it sounds like their docs may be out of date. I found a way to get the key=value arguments passed through to the crawler script even when using `runspider`.

To pass an argument you use `-a key=value`.

However, to gain access to that key/value pair, you must override `__init__` like so:

```
def __init__(self, key=None, *args, **kwargs):
```

where 'key' is the key being passed into the `__init__` function. None, here is the default value of that key (presumably). If your function signature does not perfectly match the above signature, it will not work. My script previously just had `self` passed in. I could not access the key or value in that case.

Inside the `__init__` function with the above signature you must have this as the very first line:

```
super(SpiderClassName, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

where SpiderClassName is the name of the class of the spider that you've instantiated.

ie: `class SearchEngineSpider(scrapy.Spider):`

Then when you want to access the value of that key inside the `__init__` function, you do so like this:

```
self.key
```

for example:

```
print('key value: ', self.key)
```

where 'key' is the name of the key you've passed using -a

You can also apparently refer to the self.key throughout the code inside the class, not just the `__init__` function.

Comment: “When I use crawl, it's not even a supported command” What?! If the `scrapy runspider` command exists, the `scrapy crawl` command must exist as well.

Comment: Here's a screenshot of `scrapy crawl` not existing. You can see the version printout as well. Also when you query all the commands, `crawl` isn't even listed. https://i.ibb.co/dK1Yhfw/no-Command-Crawl.png

Comment: Oh, I think I know what’s going on. It only works within a Scrapy project (see https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html#crawl).

Comment: That's probably the case. I didn't/don't want to set up a scrapy project. I just have one script I want to run. Hence using `scrapy runspider`. Thanks for the help.